# How to fit iframe and div in 100% height combined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm having difficult times to find a way to fit an iframe and div both with 100% full height on the page. Ideally I need to have a footer menu with 280px height and the iframe div needs to cover the rest of the page.

As far as I researched, it will be possible only with jQuery. I tried CSS Flex without success.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <header class="header-flex">

                <div class="map">
                    <h2>One</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ut.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="footer">
                    <h2>Two</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ut.</p>
                </div>

            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the CSS you used?

Comment: Sure. Posting it on a new answer

Comment: It doesn’t have to be flexbox, for simple stuff like this `calc` usually does the job as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example with CSS Flexbox:

```css
body,
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.header-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.map {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}
.footer {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-flex">

  <div class="map">
    <h2>One</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ut.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <h2>Two</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error ut.</p>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Considering I need to load a html file on the first div, would you recommend jQuery or iframe loading?

Comment: That depends on many things. But if it's part of the whole page, I'd prefer loading it via Ajax. Or serving it in the original HTML file directly without the need of loading it later.